# Can I power off the Android emulator?

Tags: android

In the Android emulator, I click the Power button on the right corner.
The following screen keep run, it seems I can't power off the emulator. Right?

[image]

Comment: just close the window, you don't need to shut off the emulator before you close it.

Comment: In order to test, so I need power off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:
This was answer many many years ago. things have changed since then, and you are better off with the built in AVDs in Android Studio.

You can give it a try to [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/), it is a full OS system with different configurations, is very fast and you can turn it off if you need, is a virtual machine.

Comment: This is not a good answer for the question. The poster said "how can I turn off the android emulator" and you said "try this other emulator". I actually answered the question below.

Comment: @MikeHardy my answer is from over 7 years ago, when the built in emulator was crap and using other alternatives was better. The android team has come up a long way. And you were able to turn off the built in emulator many years ago, but not when this was asked and answer.

Comment: A very valid point Jorge - I'll edit my answer to make it clear that it is a matter of all the years passing. Edit: I cannot edit my comment anymore - but for the avoidance of doubt, yes at that the time this probably was a good answer. But in 2022 luckily we don't need 3rd party emulators. More difficult to shut them off now though! :-). Cheers

Answer (score 15):

This is the stackoverflow that comes up when you search for *"android 12 emulator power off"*

You might search for that because Android 12 has taken over the "long-press the power button" gesture and turned that into "Start Google Assistant" with no ability to override it.

So how do you turn off Android 12 emulators? Not with the power button.

**Drag the notification bar down twice so it is fully expanded, and you'll see Android 12 added a software power button to the bottom middle of the quick settings.**

Long-press that, and you get the power menu you expected prior to Android 11 from a long-press on the hardware (or emulated) power button.

[image]

Cheers

Comment: great idea, will do. seems so simple, but honestly after doing android dev for years this kind of stumped me ;-)